# Magento 1.7 - add column to sales_flat_order_item

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

If I add these columns:

```
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE sales_flat_order_item add COLUMN shipping_status_id int");
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE sales_flat_quote_item add COLUMN shipping_status_id int");
```

And run this test 2 times:

```
    $o = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item');
    $o->load(92);

    print $o->getShippingStatusId() . "\n";

    $o->setShippingStatusId(123);
    $o->save();
```

I see nothing.

If I drop the columns and add:

```
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE sales_flat_order_item add COLUMN shipping_status int");
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE sales_flat_quote_item add COLUMN shipping_status int");
```

And run this test 2 times:

```
    $o = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item');
    $o->load(92);

    print $o->getShippingStatus() . "\n";

    $o->setShippingStatus(123);
    $o->save();
```

Then it works, value is saved and I can get it back.

The difference is `_id` in the column. Why does this not work in the 1st example? Is there something special about it? I checked it a couple of times.

Did another test, added both columns:

```
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE sales_flat_order_item add COLUMN shipping_status_id int");
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE sales_flat_order_item add COLUMN shipping_status int");

$installer->run("ALTER TABLE sales_flat_quote_item add COLUMN shipping_status_id int");
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE sales_flat_quote_item add COLUMN shipping_status int");
```

Test:

```
        $o = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item');
    $o->load(92);

    print $o->getItemId() . "/" . $o->getShippingStatusId() . "\n";
    print $o->getItemId() . "/" . $o->getShippingStatus() . "\n";

    $o->setShippingStatusId(123);
    $o->setShippingStatus(456);
    $o->save();
```

Only `456` value is set and get.

`/var/cache` is deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to delete Magento cache physically (/var/cache/) after columns adding. Zend caches your table structure, so it needed to be refreshed after update.

Also, try to use

```
$o->setData("shipping_status_id", 123);
```

Try to use debugger to understand problem better.

Also you may do

```
$o->setShippingStatusId(123); 
var_dump($o->getData());
```

and check if 'shipping_status_id' exist in data

Comment: I have deleted complete `/var` folder, but same results. Tested again and added both columns this time. Same results.

Comment: Try to do $o->setData('shipping_status_id, 123); Do it return the same result?

Comment: `$o->setData("shipping_status_id", 123)` works! Weird that `$o->setShippingStatusId(123);` does not work.

Comment: I modified my answer. So, is this solution fine for you?

Comment: Try to use debugger to understand problem better. Also you may do $o->setShippingStatusId(123); var_dump($o->getData()); and cheeck if 'shipping_status_id' exist in data